# postincrement operation in same statement

Tags: c++, post-increment

the question is to understand how the standards define or allow to handle these situations and what would be behaviour in this particular case wherein the variable undergoing post/pre increment is used in same statement as that of expression, when it is being used as argument to function call.

take for example following sample code

```
char a[SZ];
```

which of the following would be correct?

```
strlcpy(&a[i++],"Text",SZ-i-1);

strlcpy(&a[i++],"Text",SZ-i);
```

if the

> "," comma

would used for computation of i++ or

> ";" semicolon

??

Comment: @tobi303   the point of example is to understand how it works in this situation. and yes I am a lazy programmer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, since the "comma separated expressions" are parameters of a function (`strlcpy`), the order of evaluation of the expressions is unspecified, even in C++17.
However, C++17 guarantees that expression evaluation won't be interleaved between arguments, so that each expression is fully formed before forming another one.
So, in your `strlcpy(&a[i++],"Text",SZ-i)`, you cannot rely on the value of `i`: it could exhibit a different behavior depending on your implementation. Though since it's not undefined behavior, you know it's either going to be the old value of `i`, or the old value plus one.